# Pentaho CDE Dashboard BI (Auto refresh + Onclick refresh Functionality ) Creates Error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pentaho, dashboard

I Created Dashboard with 4 tabs and multiple components(Bar graphs, Pie charts. Tables) on Each Tabs

I am trying to show Live Data on On it from MySQL Database ..

Auto refresh : - So i keep rendering all components of Selected tab for 60 secs using

```
Dashboards.update(render_Componentname);
```

Onclick refresh :- also i have same render call in Layout panel with java Script for Tab onclick render for respective Components

I used this Function for resizing component in Pre Execution

```
var myself = this;
myself.chartDefinition.width = myself.placeholder().width();


if (!this.resizeHandlerAttached){

var debouncedResize = _.debounce(function(){
  myself.placeholder().children().css('visibility','visible');
  myself.chartDefinition.width = myself.placeholder().width();
  myself.render( myself.query.lastResults() );
}, 200);  

$(window).resize(function(){

  if ( myself.chartDefinition.width != myself.placeholder().width()){
    myself.placeholder().children().css('visibility','hidden');
    debouncedResize();
  }    
});

 $("#link1").click(function(){
    myself.placeholder().children().css('visibility','hidden');
    debouncedResize();
});


this.resizeHandlerAttached = true;
```

So while Navigating through Tabs I am getting following error (For Each component which includes above function)

```
Error :- "Uncaught NoCachedResults "
```

i doubt (as it render again with Onclick Javascript in Layout panel) may be it is conflicting ..

I am getting Error in console for this line of Code

```
code :- myself.render( myself.query.lastResults() );
```

I checked cdf-bootstrap-script-includes.js from this error is coming

Any Example for Same which includes Auto refresh + Onclick tabs refresh

Please help me with this

Thanks in Advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved Finally..!!

Issue was with calling Same function for my htmlobject which is of no use  ,component was rendering anyways , so removed .

Updated function

```
var myself = this;
myself.chartDefinition.width = myself.placeholder().width();


 if (!this.resizeHandlerAttached){

   var debouncedResize = _.debounce(function(){
     myself.placeholder().children().css('visibility','visible');
     myself.chartDefinition.width = myself.placeholder().width();
     myself.render( myself.query.lastResults() );
   }, 200);

   $(window).resize(function(){

     if ( myself.chartDefinition.width != myself.placeholder().width()){
       myself.placeholder().children().css('visibility','hidden');
       debouncedResize();
     }    
   });

  this.resizeHandlerAttached = true;
```